# Error while running simple app in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Am new to Titanium App Development and am using Fedora Operating System and Titanium Studio with Titanium sdk 3.1.2.GA to develop App. When I create and run a sample program, its showing the following issue.

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 2596, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 2400, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     launched, launch_failed = self.package_and_deploy()
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 1881, in package_and_deploy
[ERROR]     self.keystore_alias], protect_arg_positions=(6,))
[ERROR]   File "/root/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.2.GA/android/run.py", line 45, in run
[ERROR]     process = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
[ERROR]     errread, errwrite)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
[ERROR]     raise child_exception
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 29s 938ms
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Please do help me out of this.

Comment: Before doing a minus, inform whats the reason. Even people having thoughts of helping will also cant if these minus votes are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out the build folder and attempting to rebuild it again.

It seems that [this happens quite a bit](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/126896/help-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) especially when upgrading to new versions

Comment: Thank you Paul. Actually the problem is I configured to use fedora open jdk and after I reconfigure to use oracle jdk, it works. Sorry.